# Access clipboard without xclip or special registers

Tags: vim, clipboard

I'm writing a small set of mappings, to achieve the function of copying and pasting between vim and the system clipboard/selection clipboard. So far, I have good integration with `xclip` working, but some of the machines I'm working with have neither `xclip`, nor graphical/clipboard-enabled vim installations.

I'm wondering how I may, if at all, integrate with the system clipboard without these enhancements.
If it is not possible, I am open to partial solutions, eg I currently have a second-best which yanks to `cat`, which allows me to select the text to copy, but still no way to paste easily.

Here's the relevant snippet from my `.vimrc` (copied using the mapping, too):

```
" System yank and put
if executable('xclip')
    " Yank and put with the system clipboard
    nnoremap <silent> <leader>p :let @@ = system('xclip -o')<cr>""p
    nnoremap <silent> <leader>P :let @@ = system('xclip -o')<cr>""P
    nnoremap <silent> <leader>Y V""Y:call system('xclip -i', @")<cr>
    vnoremap <silent> <leader>Y V""Y:call system('xclip -i', @")<cr>
    vnoremap <silent> <leader>y ""y:call system('xclip -i', @")<cr>
    vnoremap <silent> <leader>p <esc>:let @@ = system('xclip -o')<cr>gv""p
    vnoremap <silent> <leader>P <esc>:let @@ = system('xclip -o')<cr>gv""P
else
    " Display the text for easy selection
    nnoremap <silent> <leader>Y V""Y:echo @"<cr>
    vnoremap <silent> <leader>Y V""Y:echo @"<cr>
    vnoremap <silent> <leader>y ""y:echo @"<cr>
endif
```

Edit: I'm not using `:'<,'> w !cat` because that only works linewise. Using registers as a middleman allows for character precision.

Edit: For reference, here's the output of `vim --version|grep clipboard` on one of the computers I use, which doesn't have clipboard support:

```
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
```

Comment: Could you check if you can access system clipboard from vim? run `vim --version` from console. if you have `+xterm_clipboard`, you can use system clipboard using `set clipboard=unnamed`  "
`set clipboard=unnamedplus`

Comment: @sudobangbang I know that I have no such access on the machine in question, and even if I did, I would want my script to have some functionality on machines that don't. That was what I meant by "clipboard-enabled vim".